# I am making a calculator and I get TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I was making a graphic calculator and I just received an error.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry('680x815')
window.resizable(width=False,height=False)
photo_bg = PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\behrad\calc.png')
label_bg = Label(window,image=photo_bg)
label_bg.place(x=30,y=0, height=780)
photo_0 = PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\behrad\calc.0.png')
button_0 = Button(window,photo_0)

window.mainloop()
```

I receive the error at this line:
`button_0 = Button(window,photo_0)`
and error:
`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`
I think this problem has arisen because I'm setting the photo image wrong.

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve], and preferably one that doesn't require images.

Comment: Try changing button_0 = Button(window, image = photo_0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @derek suggested in the comments, you may try `button_0 = Button(windows, image=photo_0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this:

```
photo_0 = PhotoImage(file="calc.0.png")
button_calc = tk.Button(root, text="ButtonText", image=photo_0 , command=print_hello)
button_calc.pack()
```

where *photo_0* is your image, images and *print_hello* is the function for button use.